# Mouse cursor dissapears when long-pressing Alt in Gedit

Tags: unity, mouse, gedit

When I press <kbd>Alt</kbd> in Gedit, and hold it for two seconds or so, the mouse cursor disappears, and then as I continue moving the mouse, the cursor starts flickering. The flickering happens only inside the writing area.

If I short press it, the HUD is activated, and the flickering is not.

Even when I release <kbd>Alt</kbd>, the cursor is still flashing, until I:

- change focus to some other app by clicking on it and then switch back to Gedit
- start dragging the window by its border
- press <kbd>Alt</kbd> again

Ubuntu version: 14.10.

This doesn't happen on my laptop which has the same software versions.

What's going on and how can I get it back to normal?

Comment: I opened this bug regarding a similar issue I am experiencing: https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/gedit/+bug/1387219.  See if this is the same issue you are having and add information to the bug report to help pinpoint the issue/cause.

Comment: I have somehow fixed the problem with gedit but I'm not entirely sure how but I'll elaborate encase it helps with finding a proper solution. Basically I installed GTK3.14.4-1 which removed ubuntu-desktop and some other apps. I then reinstalled the missing apps and then restarted my system and gedit was working again but the GTK3.14.4-1 package was broken and I couldn't install any new packages at all so I reverted GTK3 back to GTK3.12.2-0ubuntu15 to fix the broken packages but as far as I can gather the problem with gedit is now fixed.

Answer (score 3):

Yes! It seems to be this Bug:

[bugs.launchpad.net/.../1376494](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/gedit/+bug/1376494)

[bugs.launchpad.net/.../1387219](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/gedit/+bug/1387219)

**Solution:**

```
sudo apt install ibus-gtk
# Logout/Login
```

There are some other Tools affected by this Bug i think ...
e.g. gobby

My Hardware is an old Dell Vostro 3500 with SSD-Upgrade

```
$ uname -a
Linux V3500 3.16.0-28-generic #38-Ubuntu SMP Fri Dec 12 17:37:40 UTC 2014 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux

$ lsb_release -a
No LSB modules are available.
Distributor ID: Ubuntu
Description:    Ubuntu 14.10
Release:    14.10
Codename:   utopic
```

Answer (score 0):

If I recall correctly, I've noticed this happening on Utopic, but not on Trusty.

I use AMD hardware (my desktop uses either a HD 2400 PRO or a HD 7850; laptop uses a 7660G + 7670M on muxless; both use oibaf's PPA and relatively up-to-date kernels (3.18rc1 atm)). I've seen it happen on both computers.

Comment: Indeed, I have only experienced this issue on Utopic. Furthermore, desktop has all-AMD hardware, which includes the CPU, GPU, and a compatible mobo mainly. My laptop, which also has Utopic, but Intel hardware, doesn't have this issue.

Answer (score 0):

Installed ibus-gtk (ibus-gtk3 is already installed) and now everything is working properly.

Answer (score -2):

I noticed a mouse problem with gedit too (just moving into the window without pressing alt). You can install pluma, the MATE fork, to solve the problem:

sudo apt-get install pluma

Alternatively, you can install geany from universe:

sudo apt-get install geany

Comment: I think this is just a symptom, indicative of another problem, and I'd like to solve the actual underlying issue. It doesn't appear on my laptop as I've said,